# Email Form Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, email, swift3, gmail

Estoy tratando de crear una vista para enviar mensajes a destinatarios que estarán en una base de datos en CoreData, me gustariá si alguien sabe como poder implementar una vista así como la de Gmail.

Que en el para se pudieran se desplegara la lista de los contactos, hacer busquedas y mostrar los seleccionados.

[image: ejemplo 1]
[image: ejemplo 2]

Alguien me pueda orientar como poder implementarlo

Answer (score 1):

La clase MFMailComposeViewController te ofrece la vista que quieres.
El inconveniente por lo que quieres es que puedas acceder desde esa vista a unos correos disponibles en CoreData, ya que desde esta vista solo accedes a los correos de tu agenda.
Una posible solución sería que tú crearas primero una vista en la que accedas a esa lista de correos y los puedas seleccionar, para después presentar MFMailComposeViewController con los correos ya elegidos.

```
import MessageUI

class vistaCorreos: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

var arrayCorreos : [String] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: UIButton) {      
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(arrayCorreos)
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("") //Puedes predeterminar un asunto o dejarlo vacío
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)
    self.present(mailComposerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                       didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    // Aquí puedes comprobar si se ha enviado o no y cerrar al terminar
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Aquí puedes encontrar la 
[documentacion de apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)